# How to fix this error in a Pythagorean theorem

Tags: python, task, python-3.7, valueerror, quest

So i have easy program that will tell me if this Pythagorean theorem a2 + b2 = c2 is true or false.

But there is one problem if I try to activate it like 2 times without typing something program  will fail
Is there anything how to fix it.

```
a=int(input("enter a number a:"))    
b=int(input("enter a number b:"),)      
c=int(input("enter a number c:"),)

result= (((a**2)+(b**2)) == (c**2))     



print(f"result =  {result}")
```

here is error ValueError:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Comment: Put your `int(input(` statements in a `try... except` block; or validate that the inputs are numeric (with `.isdigit()` for instance) before casting them to `int`

Comment: What do you mean by "try to activate it like 2 times"? What does "activate" mean here? Do you mean that you just press Enter without typing anything?

Comment: @Code Apprentice yeah just start the program 2 times consecutively
  this will happen. It's normally working if you run the program but if I would say someone start the program 2 times consecutively this will show up

Comment: @DanielM_D How do you run this? Are you using the command line or an IDE or something else?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice visual studio code

Comment: I think you need to add error handling such as the suggestion from @gimix to add `try..except`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just pressed Enter without typing any numbers. If you do that then `input()` will return an empty string and `int("")` will cause the error. This is because `int` expects a valid numerical string passed to it.

To solve the problem, you need to disallow empty input. You can add error handling with a while loop to check the entered value and ask the user to enter a correct value.

Comment: @nope I start program and start it again 2 times and this will show up pretty much.